# Compiling with -nodefaultlibs causes link error for Linux system calls

Tags: linux, system-calls, libc++

I need to compile with my custom libc++. So I'm using following for compiler flags:

```
-nostdinc++ -isystem ${MY_LIBCXX_INC}
```

and this for linker flags:

```
-nodefaultlibs  -L ${MY_LIBCXX_LIB} -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc
```

This causes link error for any call that tries to use `#include <sys/stat.h>` and `stat(path, buff)` system call.

If I replace `-nodefaultlibs` with `-stdlib=libc++` I don't get this link error.

Can someone explain why is this happening? Ideally, I want to enforce `-nodefaultlibs` to absolutely make sure somehow default libs such as libstdc++ or something else don't get linked in to.

**More info**
Here's the detailed error from linker with `-v` option:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nostdinc++'
 "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o ../../output/bin/MavLinkTest /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbegin.o -L/home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/llvm-build/output/lib -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.9/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -lc++ -lm -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc CMakeFiles/MavLinkTest.dir/home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/MavLinkCom/MavLinkTest/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/MavLinkTest.dir/home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/MavLinkCom/MavLinkTest/UnitTests.cpp.o CMakeFiles/MavLinkTest.dir/home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/MavLinkCom/MavLinkTest/Commands.cpp.o -lpthread ../../output/lib/libMavLinkCom.a -lc++abi -lpthread /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
../../output/lib/libMavLinkCom.a(FileSystem.cpp.o): In function `mavlink_utils::FileSystem::isDirectory(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)':
/home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/MavLinkCom/common_utils/FileSystem.cpp:144: undefined reference to `stat'
../../output/lib/libMavLinkCom.a(FileSystem.cpp.o): In function `mavlink_utils::FileSystem::exists(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)':
/home/shitals/GitHubSrc/AirSim/MavLinkCom/common_utils/FileSystem.cpp:158: undefined reference to `stat'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Does the `sys/stat.h` you got correspond to the `lc` you're linking against?  If you are compiling with `clang`, try the `-###` and `-v` to see more details.

Comment: Oh, if `$MY_LIBCXX_LIB` refers to symbols in libc then it will have to come after it in the link line.  Add `-lc` last or wrap it in `--start-group`/`--end-group`.  For better help, please include the specific link error.

Comment: @BrianCain - thanks for reply. I tried out putting -L before -lc without any change in error. I've also added the detailed log using -v in linker option in my question above. Any insights would be great!!

Comment: Move those object files and archives to before the things they refer to (libc, etc) or use `--start-group`/`--end-group`.  Sorry, I didn't notice that the `$MY_LIBCXX_LIB` was a search path, that might not be related to this failure.